# Logical negation SAP UI5 Filter

Tags: sapui5

I have smartFilter with smart table and I am trying to exclude item from result. I have following code:

```
var oBindingParameters = oEvent.getParameter("bindingParams");

var currVal = this._aItemsForLink[0];
    var filter = new Filter({filters:[
        new sap.ui.model.Filter("RevisionNumber", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, currVal.RevisionNumber),
        new sap.ui.model.Filter("CompanyCode", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, currVal.CompanyCode),
        new sap.ui.model.Filter("FiscalYear", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, currVal.FiscalYear),
        new sap.ui.model.Filter("Invoice", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, currVal.Invoice),
        new sap.ui.model.Filter("InvoiceYear", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, currVal.InvoiceYear)
                ],and : true});

        oBindingParameters.filters = [filter];
```

Is there a way to implement logical negation for this filter?
Something like:

```
WHERE NOT ( companycode = '...' and revisionnumber = '...' and accountingdocument = '...' and invoice = '...' and fiscalyear = '...' )
```

Comment: You could turn it around into `WHERE ( fld NE '..' OR fld NE '..' .......` or something?

Comment: [SAP UI5 Demokit link for Filter operators](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.FilterOperator/properties)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A logical expression of the form **NOT ( V1 = C1 and V2 = C2 and ... Vn = Cn )** is identical to this: **V1 ne C1 or V2 ne C2 or ... Vn ne Cn**.
So, in your case it would be:

```
var filter = new Filter({filters:[
            new sap.ui.model.Filter("RevisionNumber", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.NE, currVal.RevisionNumber),
            new sap.ui.model.Filter("CompanyCode", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.NE, currVal.CompanyCode),
            new sap.ui.model.Filter("FiscalYear", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.NE, currVal.FiscalYear),
            new sap.ui.model.Filter("Invoice", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.NE, currVal.Invoice),
            new sap.ui.model.Filter("InvoiceYear", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.NE, currVal.InvoiceYear)
            ],and : false});
```

Keep in mind though that NE (Not Equal) operator in SQL WHERE clause can be very expensive when applied to key fields.